# Update Permutations in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am trying to write TSQL to update the following case.

This is sample table from database. There will be a lot of rows with different names in the table.

[image]

Upload company name and country from an Excel file.
The following is the excel data :

[image]

If (a part of the company = Column A AND country = Column B)
I would like to get the following result.

[image]

Do I need to loop the table ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have table1 contain the first sample data, table2 contain the company and contry.

You could try this:

```
select t2.*, REPLACE(t2.company, t1.a, t1.c) as result
  from table2 t2
  join table1 t1
    on t2.company like '%'+t1.a
   and t2.contry = t1.b
```

Comment: I only have 1 table(the first pic). The company and country will come from excel file. I would like to check whether a part of company from excel file and t1.A matches or not. I have updated the pics. Is it possible to check like that ?Thanks

Comment: @Lamin You said `Upload company name and country from an Excel file`, so I think you have those data in your database. If the second data in excel, why don't load it into the database?

Comment: I need to load into separated database (matched database and unmatched data.) That's why I would like to check that logic before loading into database. Thanks.

Comment: Excel is not a suitable tool to do transformation. You could load all data into one database, then transform it and split to two seperate part， keep one part in the database, and export another part to the other database.

Comment: @Jugar, Thanks for your help and suggest. But, according to your script, the result will be "abc (P) Limited Pty. Ltd.", "bcd (P) Ltd Pvt. Ltd.". I would like to get like "abc Pty. Ltd", "bcd Pvt. Ltd".

Comment: @Lamin Sorry my bad. You could use `replace` instead of `concat`, see my updated scripts, and reference to this document(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

Comment: @Judge, many thanks for your help. :) If we have the records in the table like ID (2 and 3), "bcd (P) Ltd" will be updated as "bcd (P) Ltd.". Do we need to update the script a bit ?

Comment: As I can image `bcd (P) Ltd` will generate two rows, one results to  `bcd (P) Ltd.` another to `bcd Pty. Ltd.`. Nothing could do to fix this problem, unless you change input data `bcd (P) Ltd` to `bcd | (P) Ltd` with a special character like `|` in. Then you could use `REPLACE(t2.company, '| ' + t1.a,  t1.c)` to prevent above situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jaugar. :) I checked if the result is "Ltd.", then check again if there is another result without "Ltd.", use that. if else, use the result with "Ltd.". I appreciate your kindly help.